# Sem resposta ao tentar rodar proxies em Python

Tags: python

Estou tentando escrever um código para fazer meu próprio scrapping na Web e estou tentando implementar a rotação de proxy, mas não estou obtendo nenhum resultado. Eu verifiquei muitos sites e fóruns sobre esse problema, mas não consigo fazê-lo funcionar. Aqui está parte do código que estou usando, a lista de proxies vem do site https://www.sslproxies.org/

```
p = get_proxies()
p_pool = cycle(p)
url = 'https://youtube.com'

for i in range(1,50):
    proxy = next(p_pool)
    print("request #%d"%i, proxy)
    try:
        response = requests.request(url, proxies={"https": proxy, "http": proxy}, timeout=10)
        print(response.json())
    except:
        print("Skipping. Connection error")
```

Recebo sempre a mesma mensagem de erro:

```
request #1 118.200.73.124:8080
Skipping. Connection error
request #2 103.242.44.80:8080
Skipping. Connection error
request #3 82.200.233.4:3128
Skipping. Connection error
request #4 109.75.47.248:53422
Skipping. Connection error
request #5 181.117.176.236:61358
Skipping. Connection error
```

Como posso fazer este código funcionar?

Muito obrigado!

Comment: Que libs você está usando?

Comment: import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from itertools import cycle
import traceback